# VBA coding to create .txt files for each sheet in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet that contains 2 columns of data `customer`, `product` and I have created a macro to separate the list into individual sheets per product which is working like a dream. Now, I want to create a Text (MS-DOS) `.txt` file for each of the sheets and for them to save in a specific location.

Not sure what information is required after this as the sheets that are created are just 1 column with the customers name the sheet is named after the product.

Comment: Does it need to be automated (VBA), or is a manual approach as shA.t suggests sufficient?

Comment: I was looking more towards an automated resolution due to the amount of sheets being created I was hoping to speed up the current process

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going. It creates a new .txt file for each worksheet in the workbook, saving to the same directory as the workbook itself is in.

Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

```
Sub TextFileExport()

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim shtWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strFilename As String   'text file filename

    'specify output name here
    strFilename = "OutputName"

    'loop through worksheets
    For Each shtWorkSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'create new file name
        i = i + 1
        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename & "Sheet_" & i & ".txt" For Output As #1

        'loop through cells
        For Each rngCell In shtWorkSheet.UsedRange

            If rngCell.Text <> "" Then
                'print the line
                Print #1, rngCell.Text
            End If

        Next rngCell

    'close so can reopen next one
    Close #1

    Next shtWorkSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked a treat Miss Palmer you are an angel I was way off on my script

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this solution:

1. `File` > `Export` > `Change File Type` > `Text (Tab delimited)(*.txt)`
2. In *Save As ...*  window select name of text file for first sheet and <kbd>OK</kbd>.
3. Repeat saving your text files as (2).

I think, When you don't need any functionality more than this you don't need to recreate wheel ;).

---

I think you need to use this statement:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    ws.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\" + ws.Name + ".txt", _
                  FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

Next
```

Comment: I was looking more towards an automated resolution due to the amount of sheets being created I was hoping to speed up the current process